# Infinite total cross-section in Rutherford scattering

Tags: classical-mechanics, scattering-cross-section

In Greiner's Classical Mechanics, vol. 2 (Springer 2010, p. 59), he mentions that differential cross-section in Rutherford scattering diverges as scattering angle goes to 0, i.e. when impact parameter goes to zero. Then he writes: "This is due to long-range nature of the Coulomb force. If one uses potentials which decrease faster than 1/*r*, this singularity disappears."
I figure this singularity is the reason why the total cross-section in Rutherford scattering in Coulomb field is infinite. So, if, according to this text, the singularity is weakened by other type of potential (e.g. Yukawa), then the total cross-section might become finite?

I do not understand, however, how it can be finite. As long as the potential only goes asymptotically to zero (and never becomes zero), the total cross-section should be infinite (since the particle will feel the effect of the target at any distance and will be deflected), even if the potential decays very fast with *r*.

Comment: One of the reasons quantum mechanics became necessary to model experiments. It led to the bohr model  which was not adequate to fit the data.(spectra, black body ...)

Comment: Thet’s vol. 6. I’m at vol. 2 yet :-)

Comment: If you Google [Rutherford scattering infinite cross-section](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=rutherford+scattering+infinite+cross-section) you will find at least five links, including your own, under the heading *Physics Stack Exchange*.  Thus your question might well be a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical interpretation of infinite total cross section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18757/)

Comment: @Farcher Thank you. I am just curious: Have you actually read my question? Or only the title?

Comment: I did read your question and I particularly noted your comment about not yet reaching Volume 6.  I though the the link I chose would give you an *idea* of how quantum mechanics changes the analysis without bothering you with the detail. "So in quantum mechanics, many forces have a finite cross section which means that there is a high probability that the interaction between the particles makes exactly *zero* impact, even if the force is classically non-vanishing for arbitrarily high separations. . . . .

Comment: . . . .When the decrease of the potential is faster than $1/r$, the probability that there is no interaction at all goes to 100% for large enough impact parameter." and the comparison with the Classical view "In classical physics, this is formally impossible for "total cross sections" as long as the force is nonzero for any separation."

Comment: @Farcher OK thanks it clarifies a bit in the sense that it postpones it to vol. 6. :D